# ZF2: how to catch exceptions during rendering

Tags: rendering, zend-framework2

When rendering starts, my controller code is already ran. If there is an error in the view script, it usually results in an empty or half-rendered page. I have checked the code and there is no event to subscribe to, PHPRenderer just re-throws the exception:

```
    try {
        ob_start();
        include $this->__file;
        $this->__content = ob_get_clean();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        ob_end_clean();
        throw $ex;
    }
```

For controllers, there is a 'dispatch.error' event, but that does not work here. Is there any way to catch these rendering errors and log/display the error properly?

Comment: What kind of error you have in the view script?

Comment: Any PHP error that occurs during execution of the phtml file. Fatal errors result in a white page, others may ruin the rendering and sometimes can be seen with View Source, sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing in the 2.0.x branch.
For the 2.1.x branch look the other answer.

Anyway, there is no such an event you could use. But I don't think you need it. You should not be having errors in your view, since view is for displaying things only, not for business logic. So I would say you need to fix your view instead of finding a way to catch those exceptions.

As for error logs, you could check apache logs.

Comment: Thanks, that's bad news. We are accustomed to getting an email from our production server to immediately get notified of any bugs QA might have missed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 'render.error' event that you can attach listeners to. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html .